# How to prevent reflection only for some fields?

Tags: java, reflection

We all know that the keyword "private" in java for fields and methods works only in build time, while in runtime it takes 3 lines to bypass.
I am making a plugin system for something, and these plugins are jars which are loaded in my process. So, i need a way to prevent plugins from accessing some fields of my game, which must not be accessed from outside. The problem is that the "private" keyword is useless and Reflection.registerFieldsToFilter is useless too.
What i have tried:

> making the field private (field.setAccessible() bypasses)
>
> doing Reflection.registerFieldsToFilter (Class.getDeclaredFields0() bypasses)

Then what can i do to make some fields/methods/classes actually private?

Comment: WARNING! I DO NOT WANT TO GLOBALLY DISABLE REFLECTION

Comment: Have you looked at the Java Platform Module System?

Comment: The zeroth rule of security: Physical access is game over. You can't prevent people with copies of your code from meddling this way. (Even if you manage it in Java, someone could attach a JVM agent.)

Comment: As @tgdavies mentioned, the module system does restrict reflective access. Besides that, a security manager allows origin based policies so you can disable “deep reflection” for the plugins without affecting the remaining software.

Comment: @Holger A SecurityManager is indeed the best way to stop inappropriate reflection… or will be [until it’s removed](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/411).

Comment: @VGR I hope, the module protection will be sufficiently hardened until then, at least as far as possible. As chrylis mentioned, physical access means, there’s always a way to break it. But using modules together with embedding the application in a launcher that does not allow custom JVM startup options should prevent most of the easy stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `SecurityManager` is not present, there is no guaranteed way to make your field private.

To be precise, your field is safe from access if `SecurityManager` revokes **one** of the following permissions:

- `accessDeclaredMembers`: provides access to members of a class through reflection
- `suppressAccessChecks`: provides access to non-public members of a class

For reference, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html

If your `SecurityManager`

1. grants the above permissions and `getProtectionDomain`, you can call `Reflection.registerFieldsToFilter` to protect your fields by modifying the filter map. You can then also replace the SecurityManager by un-filtering the `java.lang.System.security` field and access it with reflection. However, it isn't an appropriate approach. If a plugin adds its fields to the filter map and modifies the `SecurityManager` such that the filter map is no longer accessible, the next plugin cannot repeat the same process. Also, that defeats the purpose of security managers and access modifiers.
2. grants the three mentioned permissions except for `getProtectionDomain`, you cannot filter your field while others can use reflection to access your field.
3. does not grant `accessDeclaredMembers` or `suppressAccessChecks`, then your field is safe from being accessed via reflection.

**Method 1: Set a SecurityManager**

Instead, you can have a `SecurityManager` revoking some / all the permissions above, and add getters and setters to the fields you want to be accessible to other plugins. If your plugin is not responsible for setting up an appropriate `SecurityManager`, you can put a notice on the info page of your plugin, reminding users to set up a `SecurityManager` with other trustworthy methods.

**Method 2: Obfuscation and Source Closure**

Since reflection is widely used in serialization, another way is to not make your plugin open-source, and obfuscate your code, so developers will have a hard time tracking down the field you have been talking about.

**Method 3: Make it a Web Service** but its feasibility depends on what your plugin does.

**Method 4: Deny reflection access within a module or package**
When a package does not have the modifier `opens`, it cannot be accessed via reflection outside of the module, similarly for a module without `open`. You can also define `to modulename` where only that module can access your package via reflection:

```java
module example {
    opens package.one //can be accessed via reflection
    exports package.two //can only be accessed during compilation i.e. no reflection
}
```

*I wrote a passage on bypassing a `SecurityManager` with the 3 permissions above granted, though it is a bit outdated.* https://github.com/Bernard2518141184/Disable-Security-Manager

Comment: thanks for the answer! i like the method 4, but where should i write that module open export stuff? on which file and where pls

Comment: You will need to create a module-info.java within your src folder, the root folder of all packages. Within the file is where you define your module along with those `opens` `exports` things. For more info, you can refer to https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity @VeryGudJavaDev

Btw please don't forget to accept this answer if you find it helpful! Thanks.